# Javascript: Sort an array based on their frequencies in array values in objects stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

That was a complicated explanation. Basically, what I am trying to do is go through each of the object in the 'objects' array, look at the 'choice' values, count the number of appearances of each letter, and then sort the original arrays based on frequency.

What would be the code to return 'results' using 'letters' and 'objects'? I thought about going through each object, make a new array of choice values, count the appearances, and then sort the letters array, but this is quite long and wondered if there is a shorter code to do what I'm trying to do.

```
const letters = ['a','b','c','d']

const objects = [ 
{ id: 1, choice: ['a','b'] }, 
{ id: 2, choice: ['a','b','c'] }, 
{ id: 3, choice: ['a','c'] }, 
{ id: 4, choice: ['a','c','d'] }
]; //Total count of appearances are: 'a':4, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':1 

const results = ['a','c','b','d'];
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Combine the `choice` arrays from `objects` into one huge array and then just count the `letters`

Comment: *"I thought about going through each object, make a new array of choice values, count the appearances"*. Please include the code you've tried for that. Even if you feel it is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

- Go throw the objects array.
- Calculate the frequencies of the letters and put them in an object.
- Sort the frequencies in descending order.
- Take the keys into the result array.

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const objects = [
{ id: 1, choice: ['a','b'] }, 
{ id: 2, choice: ['a','b','c'] }, 
{ id: 3, choice: ['a','c'] }, 
{ id: 4, choice: ['a','c', 'd'] }
];

const freqs = letters.reduce((acc, curr) => ({...acc, [curr]: 0}), {});
objects.forEach(({choice}) => choice.forEach(letter => {freqs[letter] !== undefined && freqs[letter]++}));

// Convert the freqs object into entries like [['a', 4], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]] and sort by the second index
const entries = Object.entries(freqs).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

// Finally takes the keys from the sorted entries array.
const res = entries.map(([key, value]) => key);

console.log('res',res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: This is not based on letters. If objects does not contain letter d for example, result does not contain d